# EXIF direction (compass) tags

Tags: android, jpeg, exif, android-exifinterface

I would like to add the compass bearing/direction to the EXIF metadata of images, however I am quite confused about the many tags in `ExifInterface` and especially, which formats to use. Could anyone please explain to me for what the different tags are used  and especially, in which format the information needs to be added (e.g. 132.00 or 132/100 ,...)?

I have read the documentation online, but I am still confused. Thanks for the help!

`ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_IMG_DIRECTION`

`ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_IMG_DIRECTION_REF`

`ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DIRECTION_MAGNETIC`

`ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DIRECTION_TRUE`

`ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_BEARING`

`ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_BEARING_REF`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `ExifInterface` but I can tell you the meaning of these tags according to the [EXIF standard](https://web.archive.org/web/20190624045241if_/http://www.cipa.jp:80/std/documents/e/DC-008-Translation-2019-E.pdf).

`GPS_IMG_DIRECTION` is the angle that the image is facing at those coordinates ranging from 0° to 359.99°
`GPS_IMG_DIRECTION_REF` is whether that direction is based upon True North (set to `T`) or Magnetic North (set to `M`)
`GPS_DEST_BEARING` and `GPS_DEST_BEARING_REF` are similar, but they detail the direction of travel needed in order to reach the destination (which, if known, would be set in `GPSDestLatitude`, `GPSDestLatitudeRef`, `GPSDestLongitude`, and `GPSDestLongitudeRef`).  This is different from the actual current direction of travel, which is held in the `GPSTrack` and `GPSTrackRef`.

I'm not sure what `TAG_GPS_DIRECTION_TRUE` or `TAG_GPS_DIRECTION_MAGNETIC` are, as there isn't a matching entry in the EXIF standard as far as I can see.  Any directional tag will have a matching reference tag detailing whether the direction is true North or magnetic North.

Comment: Thanks @StarGeek for your answer! And thanks for adding the link to the EXIF standard. I will check it out.